# How do I multiprocess a loop in a list

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a task that I could easily achieve by using python, but it takes too long for my script to finish. So I want to change it into a multiprocessing script. I have no idea how, I tried to use `threading` but that doesn't seem to fit into this case.

I need to get all the pages' URL into the list called `page_list`, then get the content of those pages and use BeautifulSoup to get certain kinds of content.
Here is what I have:

```
some_list_from_page_content_1=[]
some_list_from_page_content_2=[]
class sth():
        def get_rv_content(self,somevar_from_another_method):
                ...
                page_list=[page1,page2,page3,page4....]
                for i in range(len(page_list)):
                        Page_Content=session.get(page_list[i],headers=req_header).content
                some_list_from_page_content_1=[x for x in Page_Content if foo]+some_list_from_page_content_1
                some_list_from_page_content_2=[x for x in Page_Content if foo]+some_list_from_page_content_2
```

Comment: What does your single-processing script look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dask` parallelization.

Basically, use can achieve paralleled map functionality by using `dask.delayed` and `dask.compute`.
For example:

from dask import delayed,compute
from time import sleep

```
def fun(x):
    sleep(x)
    return x

ls = range(10)
res = [delayed(sleep)(x) for x in ls]
print res
```

will print delayed list in nano-seconds:

> ```
> [Delayed('fun-790acf2b-873d-4fd8-be07-2bc8111c4e01'), Delayed('fun-3c8c0c8e-699e-4029-ad12-8b5daefe13ad'), Delayed('fun-9da2e125-1910-4761-b1ad-23efa5f31096'), Delayed('fun-19a15dd5-5e4d-4103-8099-f3457b3cfc3a'), Delayed('fun-56d55b5e-8bb3-4ad9-8d7f-50a6509832b6'), Delayed('fun-d7efe939-7828-4d04-9c1c-60421983141f'), Delayed('fun-044ce640-7537-477e-bff8-9b0c92e62a7a'), Delayed('fun-5b833609-a268-4ef5-a8f1-acb4be4079d8'), Delayed('fun-f33e179e-7466-4763-ab08-ab735dccd8a8'), Delayed('fun-56b5eb76-85d4-4f03-8805-eeb891a14d0d')]
> ```

then using `compute` will actually execute the function (paralyzed):

```
print compute(res)
```

will print the results (faster):

> ```
> ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],)
> ```

note - to get the results `list` look for `compute(res)[0]`

---

Therefore, in your case - just replace the execution of the function in for loop with delayed, and then run compute on the final result.

Note that you might need to run the compute element-wise:

```
print [compute(r) for r in res]
```

> ```
> [(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,), (7,), (8,), (9,)]
> ```